# Overlay GPS path on custom image

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Is it possible, instead of using MKMapView to simply overlay a GPS path on, say, a black background? I don't want to see streets or labels at all.

In this case, the accuracy of the path isn't particularly important (in terms of accuracy to landforms in the real world), just the visual path drawn onto the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this being possible in two ways:

1. Create a custom `MKTileOverlay` which has `canReplaceMapContent = YES` and just return your blank or black tiles for the base map.
2. Use something like the [Mapbox iOS SDK](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk) or [MBXMapKit](http://mapbox.com/mbxmapkit) to customize the base map.

Comment: I think using MBXMapKit and customising the map to a terrain view with all black/dark gives the best aesthetic. Very easy too.

Answer (score 1):

Since the GPS path would be stored in lat-long you could use them as coordinates and draw a line on top of what ever image you want. Use a bezierpath or similar.

Comment: Can you briefly describe the process for 'draw a line'? I'm just getting familiar with the CoreLocation framework and overlays.

Comment: It wouldn't have anything to CoreLocation. You'd need to look up drawing on NSImages.